# Connecting android app with Mailchimp

Tags: android, parse-platform, mailchimp

I have an Android app that i want to connect with Mailchimp. When a new user signs up in my app i want the user email to import automatic from the app to my list in Mailchimp. Anny suggestens? Thank you! If it helps i have a Parse account connected to my Android app

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Donwload the code from https://github.com/mailchimp/ChimpBot and update URL to current MAILCHIMP url.